# How to get two value in the type of Object Json from two different API?

Tags: reactjs, api, object

I need to pass two object data from two different JSON API.

Consider the code below:

```
 componentDidMount(){
     const loginEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
        fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/users/view/${loginEmail}`,)  // first api
         .then((resp)=>{
           resp.json().then((res)=>{
             this.setState({users_data: res.data});} 
           )
         })

         const id = localStorage.getItem('id');
         fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/event/view/${id}`,) // second api
         .then((resp)=>{
           resp.json().then((res)=>{
             this.setState({
                event_data: res.data,
             });
           })
         })
    }
```

How I call the object value from the json api:

```
 render() {
        const users_data= this.state.users_data;
        const event_data= this.state.event_data;
        console.log(users_data) //I can get this two result on my console log 
        console.log(event_data)

return(
 <div className="Container">
      {
           Object.keys(users_data, event_data).map((key) =>    // not sure is it the correct way? 
               <div className="po-left-column">
               <h1>User Name: { users_data[key].name }</h1>
               <h1>Event Name: { event_data[key].name }</h1>
               </div>
        )} 
  </div>
 );
}
```

So from the above code, I can see two data(users_data and event_data) in console log, but I fail to show the data in UI? Is it anything I'm wrong?

Comment: Try wrapping your `<div className...` with parentheses. e.g. 
`map(key => ( <div> My component </div>))`

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys()` [only takes one argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). Try changing your render return to something like the below and see if its closer to your expected result

```
return (
  <div className="Container">
    <div className="po-left-column">
    { Object.keys(users_data).map((key) => <h1>User Name:{users_data[key].name}</h1>) }
    { Object.keys(event_data).map((key) => <h1>Event Name: {event_data[key].name}</h1>) }              
    </div>
  </div>
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ".map" like this.React DOM will automatically changes output whenever the state object changes. "key" attr should be used to detect this change.

```
return(
        <div className="Container">
            {
                users_data.map((value, index) => {
                    return (
                        <h1 key={'users_data' + index}>User Name:{value.name}</h1>
                    )
                })
            }
            {
                event_data.map((value, index) => {
                    return (
                        <h1 key={'event_data' + index}>Event Name:{value.name}</h1>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
        );
```